# Moving points of a line based on collision

Tags: math, geometry, collision

I have a line colliding with a sphere:
[image]

The grey spheres are the endpoints of the line.

The white sphere is colliding with the line.

The blue sphere is the point of collision.

What I want to do is essentially move the blue sphere (the point of collision) to the edge of the white sphere by moving the grey spheres (the line endpoints).

But, I want the grey spheres moved based on how close the colliding white sphere is.

e.g. in the image above, the white sphere is colliding roughly 80% to the right on the line. So the grey sphere on the left should have to perform 80% of the movement, with the left sphere doing 20%, resulting in the diagonal movement (shown below)

[image]

While a more central collision would result in equal movement from both:
[image]

Any advice on the maths required here?

What I have available in my equation is:
The collision position
The endpoint positions of the line
The position and radius of the white sphere

I'd like to use this information to move the two endpoint positions.

Answer (score 0):

So.. not as hard as I thought it would be:

```
        Vector3 d = (Vector3)lastCollisionPoint - sc;
        float dlen = d.magnitude;
        var movement = (sc + d * (r / dlen)) - (Vector3)lastCollisionPoint;

        t2.transform.position += Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, movement, lerp);
        t1.transform.position += Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, movement, 1f - lerp);
```

sc = sphere centre

lastCollisonPoint = the blue sphere collision point

t1 & t2 = the two points of the line